# Closed unit ball in $C[0,1]$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that the unit ball $B=\{\, f\in C[0,1] :\|f\|_\infty = \max_{x\in C[0,1]}|f(x)|\leq 1\,\}$ is not compact.

By taking sequence $ f_n(x) = x^n $

we can prove that $C[0,1]$ is not sequential compact with maximum  norm. Can we use the same proof to prove  closed  unit ball in $C[0,1]$ with maximum norm is not compact?

Comment: Regarding your "Of course": $\mathbb R^n$ is not compact and yet its unit ball is.

Comment: "we can prove that $C[0,1]$ is not sequential compact." Not sequentially compact... under which metric?

Comment: under max norm.

Comment: Yes, I did not realize , I am sorry about that , yes unit ball is compact in $R^n$.